# Manipulating / Using JSON created on the website

Tags: json, spring-boot

I have this Json result on my website to use on my d3.js. The problem is that i can't manipulate it or any means of using it.
[image: Json Result]

This is the controller that is throwing the JSON result on the picture above:
[image: controller]

I've tried the d3.json() function but didn't work. It won't show any input on the console.log().

```
var url = "/queries/31370100";
d3.json(url, function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

I've also tried using Ajax but it won't work either.

Comment: See this answer to your later question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60963880/d3-json-wont-execute-keeps-getting-error-400/60964324#60964324

Comment: yes and thank you for that. But for this problem i need to get the JSON that is on a webpage as indicated on the first picture which is on my localhost.

Comment: Try using the full URL - so something like http://localhost:9090/queries/31370100 ?  It maybe because the content is being served from a different port on your local server?

Answer (score 1):

Which version of d3.js are you using?  You could also try using the new d3 promise syntax with some catches to see if it is a problem with the content or the location of the request - something like this should help:

```
d3.json(YOUR_FULL_URL).then(function (data) {

    if (typeof data === 'undefined' || data === null) {
        console.error("Failed to retreive the data");
    } else {
        console.log(data);
    }
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.error("Failed to retreive the data or there was an error parsing the response: " + error);
});
```

For more info, this is a useful explanation of the promise syntax and why it's useful: https://talk.observablehq.com/t/overcoming-difficulties-with-json-data-loading-or-another-mistake/688/2

Comment: Hi, it works! But if i call the data.id, it only says "undefined"

Comment: Have a look at the names of your parameters in the JSON snippet you gave a screenshot of.  They look a little funny.  I think "id :"  should probably be "id" : "the_id_value".