# d3.json() won't execute. keeps getting error: 400

Tags: d3.js

I'm creating a dummy JSON value and is trying to show them but the problem is i keep getting this error:

[image: **Uncaught (in promise) Error: 400**]

My code snippet is below:

```
var jsonData = '[{"id":"31370100","machine_name":"GUMACA BRANCH CAM","machine_type":"CAM","operation_start":"05:04:33","operation_end":"09:04:33"}]'

d3.json(jsonData).then((data)=>{
  console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

d3.json takes a URL as the parameter.  As you have the JSON already, you probably just need JSON.parse(), and there is no need to use d3 in this instance.  So your code would look something like:

```
var jsonData = '[{"id":"31370100","machine_name":"GUMACA BRANCH CAM","machine_type":"CAM","operation_start":"05:04:33","operation_end":"09:04:33"}]'

let data = JSON.parse(jsonData);
console.log(data);
```

Comment: *"in v5, the URL cannot be local"*... where did you read this?

Comment: Sorry - my mistake, its a Chrome restriction I think.  I've edited the answer

Comment: It's still incorrect, I'm afraid. The URL can be local, that's not an issue, as long as you use a server. And that's not a Chrome thing, all modern browsers behave the same. Anyway, your answer advising OP to ditch `d3.json` is correct.

Comment: Thanks Gerardo - updated and edited that bit out to avoid further confusion!